# Reload table in model class

Tags: iphone, ios, model-view-controller, uitableview

I have one view class. In this class I have table view. In my model class I make Asynchrous ASIHTTPRequest. And I want when the operation is successful to reload data in table view. Which is good way to do this. I consider add one UITableView property to model class and use reload it. Is this good approach?

Comment: Just call `UITableView`'s `reloadData` method...

Comment: From where should I call this method? From model class?

Comment: Don't you just want `[self.tableView reloadData];` once your operation is successful?

Comment: Yes. Can I do that every time one small data is downloaded?

Comment: If one small data is being downloaded and you'll use reload data it'll download all the data and show it in your tableView.

Comment: I want to download huge amount of data 3~4 MB

Comment: That is quite a lot of data by the way. I would look into ways to reduce this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your model post notification to [NSNotificationCenter](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsnotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and your table view register for this notification and `reloadData` when it receives one.

Inside your model, when changes occur:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"uniqueNotificationName"
                                                    object:self];
```

Inside your table view controller, register for notification, for example in viewDidAppear:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(methodToCall:)
                                             name:@"uniqueNotificationName"
                                           object:nil];
```

And implement methodToCall:

```
- (void)methodToCall:(NSNotification *)notification {
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

When you are done with the table view, for example in viewWillDisappear: you need to unregister for notifications:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your model should inform te controller that is has updated (or other way around using KVO). The controller should then message the view to reload.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to reload table view you can use one of this approaches:

1. If you want to reload all **displayed cells** then you can just call `[tableView reloadData];`. Notice, that only **displayed cells** will be reloaded. So if you have, for example, 10000 cells and only 10 of them are displayed, then only for *10* cells will be recalled method `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.
2. If you want to reload particular cells then you should call following method of `UITableView` : `- (void)reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation` and provide in first operand list of cells to reload.
3. If you want to reload whole section (or number of sections) of `UITableView` then you should call `- (void)reloadSections:(NSIndexSet *)sections withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation` and provide in first operand list of sections to reload.

Hope, it will help you to choose appropriate variant.

Comment: Thanks for info but where I should call one of this methods?

Comment: Model class or controller class

Comment: @Nekto it's not a question of how to reload table view, but how to do it when model changes.

Answer (score 1):

use synchrous and gcd to load data.
when receive data call [self reload] on main queue